# Which is the best way to display bonds?

Tags: visualization-software

We know that bonds, *per se*, are only characterized after topological studies but their visualizations is an easy and fast way to see if there are "connections" between some particles.

I tested visualizations software like [Jmol](https://jmol.sourceforge.net/), [Chimera](http://www.cgl.ucsf.edu/chimera/), [Maestro](https://www.schrodinger.com/products/maestro), [VESTA](https://jp-minerals.org/vesta/en/), [Ovito](https://ovito.org/), [Avogadro](https://two.avogadro.cc/) and [VMD](https://www.ks.uiuc.edu/Research/vmd/) and each one is displaying the bonds in a different way.

As a test, here is a small system of Ni atoms:

```
4
 energy: -19.116588819886 gnorm: 0.000358126128 xtb: 6.5.1 (863dcdc)
Ni           4.15720993928297       23.06900153804784        8.00195919232334
Ni           2.44935450390468       21.62046788970323        7.87888994741951
Ni           5.58700274720514       21.36098908827675        8.26402186547672
Ni           3.87913280960721       19.91244148397218        8.14092899478043
```

The pictures below are the graphical representation in each of the software mentioned above.

The question: **Which is the best way to display bonds?** (or Which software is better representing the bonds for this system?)

Jmol: [image]
Chimera: [image]
Maestro: [image]
VESTA: [image]
Ovito: [image]
Avogadro: [image]
VMD: [image]

Comment: In vesta and ovito, there is option to add bond where specific radius of interaction is required.

Comment: Yes, all of these programs use some semiempirical rules to determine whether there is a bond between the atoms or not. Jmol and Chimera link all atoms; Vesta, Ovito and VMD appear to link none. It's all a matter of how you define a bond - which is a highly nontrivial question in general.